# Gitlab CI building dotnet core project with WPF reference

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci-runner

For a CI Project, I am using Gitlabs pipelines to build and create nuget packages. I am using the following docker image `image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1` which works for most of my projects. However, one of mine uses `GemBox Presentation` package and this uses `WPF`.

The error I get in the pipeline is:

```
$ dotnet restore
  Determining projects to restore...
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.418/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/
    Microsoft.NET.Sdk.FrameworkReferenceResolution.targets(59,5): 
    error NETSDK1100: Windows is required to build Windows desktop applications. 
    [/builds/comp/proj/PresentationImport/PresentationImport.csproj]

Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

(some wrapping for readability).

Is there a better image to use to get this to build? GitLab says the images come from [docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/) but I cannot see the image I use there, so not sure where to go from here to get this to build in the pipeline.